# How to retrieve users wall value in facebook api

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook api in my application and this is running well. I can login and able to post text on wall. But now I want to show all my wall text in application. I am writing below query but this is showing only that wall posted which is posted by this application.

```
NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  limit 50",_session.uid];


NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];

[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
```

How will I show posted wall value in application?

Comment: objective -c for Iphone. sorry :)

Comment: I am reading this link but I am not understanding how will I implement it. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: use FbGraph api see the developer documentation on facebook.

Comment: post is a single post, you need "feed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know Objective C and the SDK for it, but the graph url would be

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed`

You have to transmit a valid `access_token.` See [Profile Feed-Wall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api)

Comment: What is Access Token. I am not seeing any any type of token value when I registered my application .

Comment: How to get access token of user ?